# Android SE app crashing when opening a question with too many answers

Tags: bug, questions, answers, android-app

I recently opened a question on PPCG's meta with the android app and because I made the mistake to scroll to aggressively, the android SE app crashed.

Platform: LG / Google Nexus 5 on Android 6 (latest security release)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a question with a lot of answers (multiple hundreds should do)
2. Scroll down (or up if spawning at the bottom) aggressively (as fast as you can)
3. Continue until the app freezes and crashes (no android crash notification)

Sample Data:
[Sandbox for Proposed Challenges (more than 1k answers)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/55329) on [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The iOS app does this too.  I notice it once I've scrolled down ~15-20 answers.  I'm guessing it's due to running low on memory from all of the answers, although I wouldn't expect answers to take a lot of memory since they're mostly just text.  Could this be fixed by removing answer views from the view hierarchy when they are not visible or, if that doesn't work, unloading answers that are scrolled far enough out of view?

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.85, twice: first, it silently crashed, the second time it only froze. Using the LogCat, I got an Error log entry for: `BufferQueueProducer: [com.stackexchange.marvin/com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.BaseActivity] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count`. There's an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823953/dequeuebuffer-cant-dequeue-multiple-buffers-without-setting-the-buffer-count) regarding the error, but seems there's no solution yet, which might be another difficulty for SE devs to fix this.