# Stack Exchange app crashes on questions with too many answers

Tags: bug, android-app

When opening [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) with the Stack Exchange app, it crashes. This is probably due to the sheer amount of answers to that question (~1.4k visible ones).

Phone: Samsung Galaxy A3
Android Version: 6.0.1

Comment: Maybe a new post could be created?

Comment: Possibly, but doubtful. If you do make a meta.se post, make sure to note whether this was in the app or mobile browser.

Comment: This issue happens to me too for those questions with many questions on my android device.

Comment: I can confirm this bug. I've had the same thing many times. One workaround I've found is to use chrome instead of the mobile app. Then it loads in pages and the performance is much better.

Comment: Is there any way to move this to se meta or do I have to redo the question

Comment: Same goes in the beta version, 1.0.89.

Comment: Works fine. Same OS version, LG G5.

Comment: Works fine for me on Nougat.. it just takes a while to load. I'm on WiFi -- are you on a mobile data connection (though I doubt that would be the reason :/)

Comment: Sure you didn't [scroll](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280360/android-se-app-crashing-when-opening-a-question-with-too-many-answers)? If so, it's a dupe

Comment: I also had this same issue on WiFi JellyBean (don't remember which phone at the time).

Comment: I think it is because of 1.5GB RAM.